# Who calls db queries and http get in mvp android

Tags: android, database, web, model, mvp

I need  to write an android application which takes date from the web and database and loads on an activity. I am planning to use the mvp design pattern. 
l. The activity will load controls on the Screen.
2. On button chick, the activity will call presenter method to get mo
data from the web.

Q1: My doubt is who will call the Select method of DB class OR  HTTGet method. The model on the presenter?

Q2: The asynctask will do an HTTP get. This is present in helper class .
 But who calls the asynctask.execute. The presenter or the model?

The http response is an xml. This is available in asynctask's do In background() method.

Asynctask will call another helper to parse the XML and get all the Strings.
Q3 The helper will call the set methods of model?
Q4 Who will now tell the set method of activity to update the view?

Answer (score 2):

Q1 - The good practice is incapsulate Select method and HTTP request inside repository (Model Layer)

Q2 - AsynkTask is old approach, it has some disadvantages, probably should use RxJava?

Q3 - Transform raw response to data object need to do inside Repository. This data object then pass to listener of this network query, in your case listener is presenter.

Q4 - When presenter get data object, it notify view that data changed.

P.S. You can see this library https://github.com/MaksTuev/ferro, it present new way for managing background task.